# Cannot increment variable N by 1 using is/2 predicate

Tags: prolog

Cannot increment variable `N` by 1 using `is/2` predicate. `N` is always 0 in the repeat loop. Why? How to increment it?

```
:- dynamic audible/1, flashes/1,tuned/1.

audible(false).
flashes(false).
tuned(false).

turn :-
  N is 0 ,
  repeat ,
  (
    incr(N,N1)    ,
    N1 =:= 5000   ,
    audible(true) ,
    flashes(true) -> retractall(tuned) ,
    retractall(flashes) ,
    retractall(audible) ,
    assert( tuned(true)   ) ,
    assert( flashes(true) ) ,
    assert( audible(true) )
  ) .

incr(X,X1) :- X1 is X+1 .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `N is 0`. Variables in Prolog are not [assignables](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/words-matter/). Here's what happens if you trace your loop:

```
?- trace, turn.
Call: (7) turn ? 
Call: (8) _G492 is 0 ? 
Exit: (8) 0 is 0 ? 
Call: (8) repeat ? 
Exit: (8) repeat ? 
Call: (8) incr(0, _G493) ? 
Call: (9) _G495 is 0+1 ? 
Exit: (9) 1 is 0+1 ? 
Exit: (8) incr(0, 1) ? 
Call: (8) 1=:=5000 ? 
Fail: (8) 1=:=5000 ? 
Redo: (8) repeat ? 
Exit: (8) repeat ? 
Call: (8) incr(0, _G493) ? 
Call: (9) _G495 is 0+1 ? 
Exit: (9) 1 is 0+1 ? 
Exit: (8) incr(0, 1) ? 
Call: (8) 1=:=5000 ? 
Fail: (8) 1=:=5000 ? 
Redo: (8) repeat ? 
Exit: (8) repeat ? 
Call: (8) incr(0, _G493) ? 
Call: (9) _G495 is 0+1 ? 
Exit: (9) 1 is 0+1 ? 
Exit: (8) incr(0, 1) ? 
Call: (8) 1=:=5000 ? 
Fail: (8) 1=:=5000 ? 
Redo: (8) repeat ?
```

See what's happening there? You're repeatedly asking if 1 is 5000, which fails, and then you try again. But the value of N and N1 will never change within the body of a predicate. Prolog does not have block-scoped variables like you're accustomed to. You need to make the body of the loop into a separate predicate and use recursion to accomplish what you're trying to do. It's going to look something like this:

```
turn :- loop(0).
loop(5000) :-
  audible(true), ...
loop(N) :-
  incr(N, N1),
  loop(N1).
```

By the way, there's already a predicate `succ/2` that does what you're trying to do with `incr/2`.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't a clue what you're trying to accomplish here, but it would appear that you're trying to write procedural prolog code.

It doesn't work.

Prolog variables are write-once: having been unified with an object they cease to be variable. They become that object, until that unification is undone via backtracking.

You need to learn to think *recursively* and to use recursion loops to do what you want.

Your turn/0 predicate

```
turn :-
  N is 0 ,
  repeat ,
  (
    incr(N,N1)    ,
    N1 =:= 5000   ,
    audible(true) ,
    flashes(true) -> retractall(tuned) ,
    retractall(flashes) ,
    retractall(audible) ,
    assert( tuned(true)   ) ,
    assert( flashes(true) ) ,
    assert( audible(true) )
  ) .
```

does the following. It:

- unifies N with 0,
- increments N1 with N+1, making N1 = 1
- fails if N1 is something other than 5000 (which it is).
- On failure, the prolog engine starts backtracking...
- backtracking through incr/2 undoes N1's binding, making it variable again.
- backtracking into repeat/0, succeeds again.

At this point, you're back to where you started, with N bound to 0.

Wash, rinse, repeat.